# Should my web app use the service name and port environment variables?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a question about this feature, https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#environment-variables. Why k8s needs to inject service name and port into the pods as environment variables? Don't people always use k8s DNS to discover their services?

Could someone give a use case for when I should use them and when I should not?

Comment: In the beginning, you did not always have an DNS server in the cluster, but nowadays you almost always have it.

Comment: Yes, I remember no DNS in K8s in the early days. But I still see people using it in a cluster that has DNS...it confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on what requirement you need in your setup. From this link[1] it will describe how to use service environment variables to specify the connection URL.

On the other hand, DNS uses name to contact services instead of IP address[2]

[1]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/bridge/kubernetes-environment-variables

[2]https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/